# Flutter WebView Plugin error on android 9

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

I am Developing an android app which has a Flutter WebView Plugin to show a web page. It works perfectly on my phone (Android 8.1 LG V20). but on my friends phone (Android 9 xiaomi note 7 pro) it shows this error: [image: The webView error]

My Code: `flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.8`

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

 class WebPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;

  WebPage({
    this.url,
  });
  @override
  _WebPageState createState() => _WebPageState();
}

class _WebPageState extends State<WebPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('url = ' + widget.url);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String link = widget.url;
    return WebviewScaffold(
      url: link,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      displayZoomControls: true,
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use http in the URL. Change to HTTPS.

Comment: I need the http to work, the website does not have https. thanks for making me realize the problem @RichardHeap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your friend is seeing this error because as standard on Android 9 and up it has been made illegal to connect to `http` domains, which Google deems unsafe.
Instead you have 3 options.

## https

Use the `https` variant of your site.
Instead of loading `http://window.arian.co.ir` load `https://window.arian.co.ir`

## Opt out for your domain.

You can opt out of the security check for the `window.arian` domain.

Make a file called `network_security_config.xml` and place it in the `res/xml/` folder of the `android` folder.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">window.arian.co.ir</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

## Opt out entirely

If you want you can opt out of this security check for all the sites inside the `WebView` by placing the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` on the `Application` tag.

In your `android` folder navigate to the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

See documentation:

- https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted

Comment: Wow! This works man, perfect and quick :). Thanks! I used the third one cause I have so many http in my app.

Comment: The third option worked for me setting usesCleartextTraffic="true". Thanks

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: I tried the above options but none worked. However, the first option got me thinking of prefixing the url with "https:" before assigning it to the `initialUrl` parameter of WebView widget (package version: 4.0.5). It worked!

Answer (score 0):

if any of above solution is not working then you can try this one

```
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.disabled,
```